# Is there a debug version of libc.a on Linux like libcmtd.lib on Windows?

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb

I've found `libc.a` and `libc.so` on my Manjaro OS, didn't find `libcd.a`.

If no need `libcd.a`, how `libcmtd.lib` and `gdb` works?

What's the internal difference when using `libcmtd.lib` and `gdb` debug program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've found libc.a and libc.so on my Manjaro OS, didn't find libcd.a.

You will never find such library on any UNIX system, because UNIX systems package debug info directly into the object files.

That is, depending on how your `libc.a` is built, it will or will not contain all the debug info in itself.

Some distributions ship `libc.a` with debug info, while others do not. If your distribution doesn't, you'll have to build libc.a yourself (default build procedure does build it with debug info enabled).

However, a much simpler solution might be to link with `libc.so` instead -- most distributions allow you to install `libc6-dbg` or similar package, which magically provides debug info for `libc.so.6`.